# Can React props udpates be quick and consistent enough to keep a steady tempo and trigger notes in music app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, audio-player

I'm creating a music app that loops through a one-bar sequence and triggers notes which lie in the sequence. I'd like to have a function in a component which triggers at regular intervals (say every 10ms) using setInterval() and changes the props of the child component to tell it how far through the sequence it is. This child component, or perhaps its own child, would then trigger the notes at the appropriate times (based on the current progress through the sequence, which it gets from the props updates, and the position of the notes).

I'm aware that React updates state (and props?) asynchronously, and so my question is: would updating props in this way be quick, consistent and reliable enough to keep a steady beat and trigger the notes in the appropriate places? If not, is there another method I could use within React or a different library altogether?

Please do let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: I don't think updating all props of all children as the music moves would be the correct way, as that would trigger lots of pointless re-renders.  I would use event listeners for things like this..  If your using hooks you could then attach / detach the event using the useEffect.  What I would maybe use the props for here though, is what note it's listening for.  What I would say here though, React in itself has no effect on performance, it's how you implement it, IOW: doing this in pure JS wouldn't gain you anything..

Comment: Hi @Keith, thanks for your answer! I'm not familiar with hooks, so looking at it from a class-based component perspective do you think this sounds sensible: store the note info (i.e. its location in the sequence) in the state of a child component, and then pass that state up to the parent component in which the setInterval function is running. So every time this function is triggered it compares the position of the notes it has received to the position of the sequence, and it plays the note if they match? Presumably that would avoid needless re-renders.Thanks for your help - I'm new to React!